# How does this Example Endgame work in Scrabble? Playing Out Scenario

Tags: scrabble, end-game, notation

In Wikibook's Scrabble guide, they have a Scrabble/Endgame section.

In [the Example Endgame Subsection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scrabble/Endgame#Example_Endgame), they show how a person could play out his letters, knowing through tile-tracking that the opponent has a W. They note that the opponent has only two places to play the W, as OW or WAG. The first move they play is OTIC, blocking OW. Then they go on to play three more times, leaving the opponent with W and winning the game.

How does this work? If I were the opponent and OW was used I would play WAG directly after, ending the game.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you summarize the information from that link here?  If the linked page ever disappears/changes, your question won't be very meaningful anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Playing OTIC blocks both OW *and* WAG.  OTIC starting at H3 will put the 'C' on H6, blocking the opponent from playing W on I6.